My head seems to have fallen off
I was playing Dead Cells again recently, after a couple month hiatus, and something horrible has happened - my head has fallen off.

I stood up from the game temporarily in the starting section of the game.
The controller was upside down when I came back (I’d left it like that, I suppose), so I’m guessing a button was pressed.
Why did my head fall off? How do I put my head back on? And given it’s in the game, what’s the benefit of losing my head?

And this is a new episode of "weird title spotted on Hot Network Questions"

@pinckerman there were worse. (That's the most famous I remember. ;))

@ShadowWizard we tried to gather the best ones in an old meta post

@pinckerman I love that post.

The Memes of Arcade and its Chat is also a great one.

@pinckerman I clicked on it because it reminded me of a scene from "Grandma's Boy" which I can't really vouch for as a movie but that was part that was memorable, perhaps because I thought it was ridiculous, and then I saw this.

That's the Homunculus Rune, as the Wiki says, gotten after defeating the Hand of the King.

The Homunculus Rune allows the player detach their head and control it separately from their body to access certain areas. It can latch on to a single enemy, dealing damage to them and leaving the player with full control of the player's body. The damage is scaled on the player's highest stat. The head can also climb walls indefinitely.


The head will return to the body instantly, going through all obstacles, under any of the following conditions: Reaching the max distance away from the main body, the player taking damage while the head is latched onto an enemy, the head defeating an enemy, the head remaining attached to an enemy for ~7 seconds, or if the player presses the assigned button again.

The button is the "Leave/get back in body" button. By default this will be clicking the right stick on a controller.
